# How to capture ChaptersButton selection event in Video.js?

Tags: javascript, video, video.js

I am using a .webVTT file in a `video.js` project to provide cuepoint access ('chapters' per the image below). I've searched endlessly through the rather terse video.js docs and on the web but I have been unable to find any code examples showing how to capture the selection event when the user selects a cue.

I've tried every variation I can think of for adding an event handler to the various components which make up the [ChaptersButton](https://docs.videojs.com/chaptersbutton#getMenuCaption) component without success. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here? I need to get the selected cue times in order to display some other stuff.

```
player.controlBar.chaptersButton.on('tap', onMenuSelection)
player.controlBar.chaptersButton.on('click', onMenuSelection)
player.controlBar.chaptersButton.menu.on('tap', onMenuSelection)
player.controlBar.chaptersButton.menu.on('click', onMenuSelection)


player.controlBar.chaptersButton.on('select', onMenuSelection)
player.controlBar.chaptersButton.handleClick('click', onMenuSelection)
player.controlBar.chaptersButton.handleClick(onMenuSelection)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to a click on each of the menu items

```js
player.controlBar.chaptersButton.menu.children().forEach(c => c.on('click', handler))
```

Comment: Thanks – that worked, though to get access to the menu children, I had to use a `setTimeout` after the chapter track is added within the `player.ready`function – I guess because the menu isn't built immediately. Also had to filter the children, since there is a header/title component in the menu – by testing if `c.cue == undefined`